# Javascript variables braces html tag not interpreted

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, outlook, tags

I have a problem with the outlook API. I display mails but the body doesn't interpret html tags. I only see the source code of the page.I tried a lot of things but I can't get the tags interpreted. Anybody got a solution? Thank you

```js
      // Get the 10 newest messages
      client
        .api('/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages')
        .header('X-AnchorMailbox', emailAddress)
        .top(1)
        .select('subject,from,receivedDateTime,bodyPreview,uniqueBody')
        .orderby('receivedDateTime DESC')
        .get((err, res) => {
          if (err) {
            callback(null, err);
          } else {
            callback(res.value);
          }
        });
    } else {
      var error = { responseText: 'Could not retrieve access token' };
      callback(null, error);
    }
  });
```

```html
     <div class="test"> 
    <!-- Handlebars template for message list -->
<script id="msg-list-template">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
  {{#each messages}}
  
  <div class="list-group-item">
    <h3 id="msg-from" class="">{{this.from.emailAddress.name}}</h3>
    <h4 id="msg-subject" class="list-group-item-heading">{{this.subject}}</h4>
    <p id="msg-received" class="list-group-item-heading text-muted"><em>Received: {{formatDate this.receivedDateTime}}</em></p>
    <p id="msg-bodyPreview" class="list-group-item-text text-muted azerty"><em>{{this.bodyPreview}}</em></p>
        <p id="msg" class=""><em>{{this.uniqueBody.content}}</em></p>;
            
       
        
        
        
        

  </div>
    
  {{/each}}
```

Comment: can you show your full HTML and Node code by any chance?

Comment: I solved my problem. it was enough to add three "{" to take into account the tags.